# Water damage to wall drywall near ceiling - Should I repair or extract and replace?

Tags: drywall, repair, water-damage

A few months ago, we had a leak that caused some moderate damage to the drywall in the corner of one room. The resulting damage left peeling tape, as well as a gap between the drywall and the ceiling.

The damage to the tape is about 12 inches long, and then the more adverse damage another 12 inches, spreading out from the joint ~2in in either direction, up to the corner of the room.

Looking into this on my own, it seems like it might be possible to redo the tape and joint compound in place, but I'm not sure whether this is actually the correct procedure.

I've also seen people recommend removing a chunk of the drywall and slotting in a replacement chunk, but the details of this (how much to remove, how to ensure the replacement chunk is secure) were unclear to me.

What's the proper method of handling this type of damage?

*This question is related but not necessarily the same:* [Repairing water damage to ceiling drywall where ceiling meets wall](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/159791/repairing-water-damage-to-ceiling-drywall-where-ceiling-meets-wall)

[image: Damage to wall and ceiling - 12 inches across of peeling tape, then 12 inches across of more significantly damaged drywall]

Comment: Those brown marks in the drywall, closest to the corner, look like damage to the paper coating. Your best bet for a _long term_ fix may be to cut out a chunk of the wall about 12" tall and to the next stud past your 24" across mark and put in a patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be more of an opinion type question but I would just repair the corner and fill the small section where the paper ripped off.

Fill it put a layer of tape let it dry, put a new corner in mud let dry sand and a can of texture should fix it up. If messy with the mud it may take more sanding.

If you cut a section out there will be more repair work if the damaged area was wider and deeper I would cut out but it looks like the back paper is intact.

1 maybe 2 coats of mud should do it from what I see.

Comment: I agree that this looks repairable, assuming that it all feels solid. I'm not sure how you'd do the job with fewer than 3 applications, though. The first (prefill) coat will shrink substantially, then it'll take a fill coat and a finish coat.

Comment: I was thinking hot mud but not a good choice for a new to diy so regular mud would have more shrinkage +

Answer (score 1):

If the remaining drywall is solid, then you should be able to cover this hole with mud and tape. (First, remove the loose bit of tape on the left.)

But if the drywall is crumbling, then you need to remove the crumbly parts and then re-assess the situation. If the hole is much bigger, then you'll need to insert a drywall patch.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the entire damaged area if solid behind the area. It is easiest to fill 1 or 2 times with duro-bond 90, then tape, mud, and finish coat. Paint or texture it to match as close to the color as possible.